# Can I (US Citizen) legally travel to France and Back right now? (late May 2020)

Tags: uk, france, covid-19, england, eurostar

I have been riding out the pandemic in the UK with my girlfriend (she is a UK citizen only) but I am a US citizen.

We want to do a holiday somewhere but she can't come to the US.

But can I leave then enter the UK/enter then leave France?

We will probably drive, if that matters.

Comment: This probably depends - among other things - on your ability to (re-)enter the UK. I can't answer your question, but the following info might be helpful for somebody who can: you said you're "riding out" in the UK - am I right in assuming that means you don't live (permanently) in the UK? when did you enter the UK? Do you have a UK visa (if so, which type?), or did you enter visa-free?

Comment: Coming from the UK, you might technically be able to enter France but not move around (i.e. more than 100 km) right now. Tourism, short-term accommodation and restaurants are still severely restricted. These rules are supposed to change next Tuesday, the prime minister will announce this afternoon in what way and at what pace so I could try to write an answer after that, if you provide the details Chris asked for.

Comment: Apart from all that, from June 8, you would be subject to a 14-day quarantine period after entering France. This measure is based purely on reciprocity and its duration therefore depends on British decisions.

Comment: @Derek Fulton You and your girlfriend should also take into account the FCO travel advice for British nationals. Its warning against all but essential travel hasn’t changed yet https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/france/entry-requirements

Comment: Thanks everyone. @ChrisH No visa. I've been here 3 months—I'm allowed 6 at a time without a visa. Also, I have a place to stay in France for 14 days. Really just want to hop on the Eurostar and visit a friend who lives there.

Comment: @Derek Fulton You’re allowed a stay of up to 6 months at a time subject to https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules Genuine intention to visit
V 4.2 The applicant must satisfy the decision maker that they are a genuine visitor. This means that you:
(a) will leave the UK at the end of your visit; and
(b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK your main home

Answer (score 5):

**No**, you cannot enter France unless you have a good reason, and holidaying **currently** isn't a good reason.

Any person entering France must (currently) fill two self-certification forms:

- one that specifies the reason for entering France, from the given list
- one where the person certifies they don't have any COVID-19 symptoms...

Additionally, a 14-day self-quarantine will be required from June 8th upon entering France (and another one when returning to the UK).

The details and forms are available [on this page](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage) (scroll down for the English version and the links to the forms):

> #### 1/ In the context of the implementation of the state of health emergency in France because of the COVID-19 pandemic, access restrictions to Mainland France and to French Overseas territories are in effect.
>
> Every traveler is requested, since 8 April 2020, to **fill out and
> carry one of the following travel certificates** according to his
> situation :
>
> - **For an international travel from abroad to mainland France**
> - for an international travel from abroad to French overseas territories
> - for a trip from mainland France to French overseas territories
>
> These documents are made available below.
>
> From 25 May 2020, travelers are also requested to **fill out and carry
> with them a statement certifying they do not have any symptoms of a
> COVID-19 infection**. The statement can be found below.
>
> The certificate and the statement are to be presented to
> transportation companies before boarding, as well as to border control
> authorities.
>
> #### 2/ From 25 May 2020, the following sanitary measures will apply for international travelers upon arrival on the French territory :
>
> Travelers coming from the outside of the European space (all countries
> except European Union member states [except Spain], Andorra, Iceland,
> Liechtenstein, Monaco, Norway, San Marino, Switzerland, Holy See), as
> well as **travelers coming from the United Kingdom (from 8 June on)**
> and from Spain (by air only), will be invited to carry out **a 2-week
> quarantine at home, or in a dedicated location provided if needed,
> upon arrival in France**.

The list of allowed reasons is:

> - French nationals, accompanied by their spouse and children;
> - European Union nationals and nationals from Andorra, United Kingdom, Iceland, Liechtenstein, Monaco, Norway, San Marino, Switzerland, and
>   the Holy See, having their primary residence in France or transiting
>   through France to reach their country of origin or where they have
>   their primary residence, accompanied by their spouse and children;
> - Third country nationals, who are holders of a French or European residence permit or valid long-stay visa, having their primary
>   residence in France or transiting through France to reach their
>   residence in a country of the European Union or assimilated;
> - Third country nationals, transiting less than 24 hours in an international area to reach their country of origin and who are
>   holders of a travel document to this country;
> - Diplomatic mission staff, or international organisations staff working in headquarters or offices located in France, accompanied by
>   their spouse and children;
> - Healthcare workers supporting the fight against Covid-19;
> - Flight and cargo crews, or travelling as a passenger to their departure base;
> - Foreign nationals ensuring the international carriage of goods;
> - Goods carriers including seamen.

None of which seem to match your situation.

A few things are supposed to change in the next few days, details should be made public the afternoon by the french Prime Minister. It is however unlikely people from the UK will get additional flexibility at this time.