# Transit France by car with an overnight stay - need to self-quarantine?

Tags: uk, transit, france, covid-19

I'd like to transit France by car to travel from the UK to Italy. Given the length of the trip this would require at least an overnight stay.
The latest advice is that, following new UK regulations from the 8th of June, travellers to France will be asked to self-quarantine for 14 days.

The first exception is "people in transit to another country" (https://uk.ambafrance.org/COVID-19-UK-and-French-travel-and-quarantine-measures).

I'm not sure this is intended to cover transit in an airport or if I'm allowed to cross the country by car, and if so if I'd be allowed to stay overnight provided I keep contacts with other people to the bare minimum.

Comment: I wouldn’t really call it transiting since you are literally crossing the country

Comment: @TomasBy true, but we wouldn't be leaving from Dover and overnight stays are not allowed in the UK, so *currently* that would be a longer drive

Comment: @rosysnake The FCO is still advising against all but essential travel https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/france Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157412/can-i-us-citizen-legally-travel-to-france-and-back-right-now-late-may-2020

Comment: @Traveller thank you, the related question answer is a bit more informative, though I still can't tell if "European Union nationals and nationals from Andorra, United Kingdom, Iceland, Liechtenstein, Monaco, Norway, San Marino, Switzerland, and the Holy See, having their primary residence in France or transiting through France to reach their country of origin or where they have their primary residence, accompanied by their spouse and children;" only applies to airport transit

Comment: I am not sure about France, but other countries (Austria, Hungary) have had very strict interpretations of road transit. In both countries, cars in transit have only been allowed to stop at designated places and Austria requires (required?) incoming cars to have enough petrol to get through the country without even having to stop for fuel.

Comment: What is your reason to go to Italy? Currently you are only allowed to enter France from abroad for transit to your country or origin or primary residence. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157412/can-i-us-citizen-legally-travel-to-france-and-back-right-now-late-may-2020 and https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage (scroll down for English version).

Comment: @jcaron I would be traveling to my country of origin. I'm also not planning to travel before the 15th of June, which is when, unless there are further changes, most EU countries are planning to open borders for tourism too. Whatever that date will be I'll wait, so I'm not concerned of entering France per se, but just about the self-quarantine rule

Comment: @Daniil but that's precisely what "transit" means.

Comment: The current rules (not related to quarantine) make a difference between transiting for less than 24 hours, staying in the "international area" (airside of airports, I suppose) and other forms of transit through the country, so it is likely that rules for quarantine will be similar.

Comment: @Daniil I agree with @ phoog - when I fly into the US I give my reason for visit as "transit to Mexico by land" and that is accepted.  Only reason for the visit is for transit to another country.

Comment: @jcaron Which rules now? Visa requirements?

Comment: @Relaxed, no, you are not allowed to enter France at the moment unless it is for one of a very limited number of reasons, and you need to have a self-certification form which indicated the reason, plus another form to self-certify that you are exempt from symptoms. The list of allowed reasons includes transit to your permanent residence or country of origin in the EU/EEA for citizens and PRs, or "transit under 24 hours in the international area" to anywhere else.

Comment: @jcaron OK, I see, I misunderstood what you meant by “not related to quarantine” as these rules, being temporary rules to fight Covid-19 seemed very much related to the quarantine rules.

Comment: @Relaxed Well there's a big stack of different COVID-19 rules that are being piled one on top of each other, with different reasons and exemptions, and they change independently. At the moment there's a restricted list of valid reasons and the self-certification form that goes with it, there's the (new) requirement to self-certify you don't have symptoms, and there's the (upcoming) quarantine. All of that on top of the usual Schengen requirements, of course. The first one will probably be removed soon, but I don't think there's a date on that yet.

Comment: @jcaron Yes, what you are referring to is clear now, as I said I just misread the initial comment. The self-certification form to enter France also changed between March-April (when there was no mention of transit if you were an EU citizen or resident) and May (I initially wrote a comment about that under your answer to the other question, which I deleted when it turned out to be out-of-date). “Soon” in this context is presumably not before June 15, given yesterday's press conference.

Comment: @jcaron I think this observation is highly relevant and could form the basis for an answer, if you want to write one. It remains to be seen what the rules will actually be (and the police will probably have some leeway too) but the fact is that what the OP is contemplating is transit and whenever French authorities mean airport transit or transit within 24h they add additional qualifiers, as you pointed out.

Comment: @Relaxed I think one would need to find the actual legal text underpinning this, but I could not find anything. Note that the quarantine is actually "voluntary", apparently. The UK's weird lockdown ("please stay at home" rather than "you are ordered to stay at home") is spilling over in France, apparently.

Comment: @jcaron W.e.f. 23 March the UK’s lockdown was an instruction to stay home https://www.gov.uk/government/speeches/pm-address-to-the-nation-on-coronavirus-23-march-2020 Until the lockdown began to be relaxed, there was no weird ‘please stay home’ about it - leaving home was only allowed for very limited purposes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.